# How to display inverse text in html?

Tags: html

Having no control over the complete html document.
But inside of the html body, I need to display inverse text.

Maybe something like this:

```
<span style=\"text-decoration: inverse;\">inverted text</span>
```

Inverse text means, swapped foreground / background colors like this:

[image: inverse]

(I know, it might be a problem if there is no background color set or the background is a bitmap …)

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: What is "inverse text"?

Comment: added example bitmap for "inverse text"

Answer (score 1):

If you need "inverse" like upside down, you can try using css:

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

Or if you only want to flip it use:

```
transform: scaleY(-1);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but I mean color swapping, not text direction. Updated the question now.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that the text colour after inversion will always be black, you could do this:

```
<span style="background-color:currentColor"><span style="color:black">Text here</span></span>
```

This first sets the background colour to the current text colour, then makes the text black. It has to be in two steps otherwise currentColor will just be black again.